# How to write a shell script to run a Makefile?

Tags: shell, if-statement, makefile

I want to make a shell script to run a Makefile.

If I tap this command `./run.sh bonus`, The Rule bonus will be applied.

but if I wrote this `./run.sh`, the command `make` will apply.

I try This script but every time the command `make` apply.

```
make fclean
if [$1 == "bonus"];
then
    echo "make bonus"
else
    echo "make"
fi
make clean
./cub3D maps/1.cub
```

Comment: Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Thank You for your comment, I didn't know That there's a web site like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems.

First, you need whitespace around the `[` and `]` (since you claim `./run.sh bonus` works as expected, this is probably an omission from the question, not a problem in your actual script.

Second, `==` should not be used with `[`. `bash` allows it, but `=` is the only *portable* equality operator for `[`. If you want to use `==`, use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

Third, you need to quote `$1` with `[` so that it doesn't simply "disappear" when you run `./run.sh` with no argument.

```
make fclean
if [ "$1" = bonus ]; then  # or [[ "$1" == bonus ]].
  make bonus
else
  make
fi
make clean

./cub3D maps/1.cub
```